# Google sheet html not calling script function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following html code in my google app. IT should call the function below but I'm getting nothing. I've used the same script throughout my code until now

```
<div id= "right_column">
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Enter Grades for Selected Lessons"
      onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showMsgForLoginAttempt).generate_grades_for_lesson(this.parentNode)"/> 
    </p>

</div>
```

Here is the code for the function

```
function generate_grades_for_lesson(formObject) {
    msgBox("Hello");
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The `parentNode` to the button is a `<p>` tag in your example code.  That's not a form element.  If you want to send data from a form you'll need `<form></form>` tags.  Instead of using `msgBox()` for debugging, I'd use `Logger.log("it Ran!")` and then in the View menu, choose Logs to see what is printed to the Logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use form instead of p around the form elements. 
Use type="text" for value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id= "right_column">
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="grades" placeholder="Grades..."> 

      <input type="button" value="Enter Grades for Selected Lessons" 
      onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showMsgForLoginAttempt).generate_grades_for_lesson(this.parentNode)"/> 
    </form>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
function showMsgForLoginAttempt() {
  console.log("success");
}
</script>
```

Use Browser.msgbox in google apps script

```
function generate_grades_for_lesson(formObject) {
  Browser.msgBox("Grades: " + formObject.grades);
}
```