# Cannot call Google script from HTML page using this.ParentNode

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have asked a similar question to this. I cannot seem to get the onclick event to fire for me. Is there something obvious to someone that could help me out here. The function is written below the code.

```
<div id= "right_column">

    <form>
      <input type="button" name="enter_grades" id="enter_grades" value="Enter Grades for Selected Lessons"
              onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showMsgForLoginAttempt).generate_grades_for_lesson(this.parentNode)" /> 
    </form>


</div>
```

This is the gscript function

```
function generate_grades_for_lesson(formObject) {
    Browser.msgBox("Hello");
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing `this.parentNode` with `this.target.parentNode`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm still getting nothing

Comment: Are you getting any error message that help us to find the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google sheet html not calling script function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337839/google-sheet-html-not-calling-script-function)

Comment: Put another input into the form tags with a name.  Try using `Logger.log('it ran')` instead of `Browser.msgBox('hello')`  The in the View menu choose Logs.  Try printing something to the browser console in your `onclick` code.  In Chrome and Firefox hit the f12 key to open the browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember struggling quite a bit with this about a year ago. I did get it working after hours of tearing my hair out and let me share some of my code so that maybe it helps.

First in the `<head></head>` of your page (assuming you have a well-formed HTML page) you could add an error handler:

```
<script>
  function onFailure(error) {
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML = "ERROR: " + error.message;
  }
</script>
```

Then add an "output" div before the end of your `<body>`:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

This should output some errors that you were not aware of before when you click the button

Finally here is the "onclick" that I use:
`onclick="google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).FUNCTIONNAME(this.parentNode)"`

Hope this helps!